# How to use SCD type 1 using Delta Live Table

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I am looking for real time example for applying SCD type 1 using Delta Live Table.

I tried the reference from the official document from DLT but not able to get the exact answer.

Comment: Can you provide more information - what is your input data, how do you process data, etc.? Just edit your question

Comment: Any realtime example if you could show me in databricks. I am using python coding for ETL.

Comment: I am using a dataframe as an input source and existing table as target.